# В шаблоне компонента битрикc-1с не подключается script.js

Tags: jquery, битрикс

Я пытаюсь подключить script.js со следующим кодом:

```
//SCRIPT.JS
         $('#form-button').on( "click",function(event){
          event.preventDefault();
          console.log("res");});

Но при подключение в template.php все работает:
//TEMPLATE.PHP
<button id="form-button"  type="click" class="btn btn-primary mb-3">Отправить</button>
      </div>
       </form>
     <script> 
      $('#form-button').on( "click",function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log("res");})
    </script>

Подскажите,пожалуйста, что я делаю не так.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первом случае код написан до элемента, во втором после.

Попробуйте так:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#form-button').on( "click",function(event){
          event.preventDefault();
          console.log("res");});
}
```

Comment: Спасибо,получилось)